# PreUpdate, Update, PostUpdate... Anyone use better names?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

Does anyone use a prettier naming convention for these types of methods?  I know better is subjective but I hate them. Methods should (generally) be named as verbs.  Object.Move(), Object.Talk() not Object.PreDatabaseUpdateStep().

I've been using Think() for my PreUpdate(), which is generally pure logic compared to Update() which is generally pure physics.  I haven't thought of anything fancier for PostUpdate() yet.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pragmatic programmer should always strive to design code for readability. The names `PreUpdate`, `Update`, and `PostUpdate` communicate their intentions much more clearly than a name like `Think`.

Similarly, we can look to what other projects do for inspiration. For example, the JUnit suite uses similar naming convention with `@Before` and `@After` (and `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`) annotations. And by convention, iOS delegate patterns often specify "Will" and "Did" (like `WillUpdateFoo` and `DidUpdateFoo`) methods.

Answer (score 0):

`PreUpdate` is indeed not really specific. Probably you could make it even more clear what's happening in these methods.

Whatever replacement you find for Pre and Post. When you use the same terms in different cases, it can't have specific information. So it doesn't matter much.

What about `PrepareUpdate` and `FinishUpdate`?

There is a naming convention for this kind of events in C#, which makes use of the tense. `Updating` is called before update happens, `Updated` afterwards. Personally, I think Pre and Post is more clear to everyone, but I also use this naming convention.